# VBA range.formula issue (LEN, RIGHT & LEFT)

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm trying to do a VBA code to accomplish 2 things as follows:

Count how many characters there is on cell `A1`, using the formula `LEN(A1)` and one the last line, I'm trying to have the formula `RIGHT(LEFT(A1;Q1-2);6)` on cell `J1`

Please follow down my VBA code so far:

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR
    cel = "A" & i
    cel2 = "P" & i
    cel3 = "Q" & i

    Range("P" & i).Formula = "=LEN(" & cel & ")"
    Range("J" & i).Formula = "=RIGHT(LEFT(" & cel & "," & cel3 & "-" & 2 & ")," & 6 & ")"
Next i
```

It seems something silly what is missing, however, I couldnt manage to solve it so far

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't edit the question/code after a viable answer has been provided. Future users will not have the context for the question and the answer. I can't roll back the edit - @DisplayName are you able?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re missing a Right, and some other things

```
Range("J" & i).Formula = "=RIGHT(LEFT(" & cel & "," & cel3 & "-2), 6)"
```