# VBA excel - range.formula issue

Tags: excel, vba, formula

There is a particular part of my code which I cannot make work,

I'm trying to do the following command on VBA `=RIGHT(LEFT(X1;Z1-2);LEN(LEFT(X1;Z1-2))-FIND(":";X1))`

On cell `X1`, there is a text: `RESULTS:NG & MODEL:IJ`

My VBA code is:

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR
   cel = "A" & i
   cel2 = "Y" & i
   cel3 = "Z" & i
   cel4 = "X" & i

   Range("M" & i).Formula = "=RIGHT(LEFT(" & cel4 & "," & cel3 & "-" & 2 & "),LEN(LEFT(" & cel4 & "," & cel3 & "-" & 2 & "))-FIND(:" & cel4 & "))"

Next i
```

I'm open for a better approach for this issue as well

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a general rule of thumb `FormulaR1C1` is easier to use from VBA than `Formula`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA range.formula issue (LEN, RIGHT & LEFT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553724/vba-range-formula-issue-len-right-left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing all the formulas at once and reduce using quotes within the formula as much as possible.

```
   Range(Cells(1, "M"), cells(lr, "M")).Formula = _
     "=RIGHT(LEFT(X1, Z1-2), LEN(LEFT(X1, Z1-2))-FIND(char(58), X1))"
```

All range and cells reference within a sub procedure are better with a properly defined parent worksheet reference.

```
dim lr as long
with worksheets("sheet1")
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(1, "M"), .cells(lr, "M")).Formula = _
      "=RIGHT(LEFT(X1, Z1-2), LEN(LEFT(X1, Z1-2))-FIND(char(58), X1))"
end with
```